# Which bibliographic styles support the `orig` fields?

Tags: biblatex

In the documentation of the biblatex package, it is said that the majority of bibliographic styles do not support the `origpublisher`, `origdate`, … fields (i.e. display properly the information filled in).
In fact I did not find a single one which does. Is it because there are none?

Here is an example of a bibliographic entry for test use.

```
@book{Kro04,
    author = {Pierre Kropotkine},
    isbn = {9782842058371},
    language = {french},
    origdate = {1889},
    origlocation = {Paris},
    origpublisher = {Les Temps nouveaux},
    pagetotal = {95},
    publisher = {Mille et une nuits},
    title = {La morale anarchiste},
    year = {2004}
}
```

I am using `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}` and `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `biblatex` styles do not use the `orig...` fields (except for `origlanguage`) instead preferring the `related` feature.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Kro04:orig,
  author        = {Pierre Kropotkine},
  isbn          = {9782842058371},
  language      = {french},
  origdate      = {1889},
  origlocation  = {Paris},
  origpublisher = {Les Temps nouveaux},
  pagetotal     = {95},
  publisher     = {Mille et une nuits},
  title         = {La morale anarchiste},
  year          = {2004},
}
@book{Kro04:related,
  author        = {Pierre Kropotkine},
  isbn          = {9782842058371},
  language      = {french},
  pagetotal     = {95},
  publisher     = {Mille et une nuits},
  title         = {La morale anarchiste},
  year          = {2004},
  related       = {Kro04:old},
  relatedtype   = {reprintof},
}
@book{Kro04:old,
  author    = {Pierre Kropotkine},
  language  = {french},
  date      = {1889},
  location  = {Paris},
  publisher = {Les Temps nouveaux},
  title     = {La morale anarchiste},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,Kro04:orig,Kro04:related}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Kropotkine, Pierre(2004b). La morale anarchiste. French. Mille et une nuits. 95 pp. isbn: 9782842058371. Repr. of La morale anarchiste. French. Paris: Les Temps nouveaux, 1889.]

But some contributed styles use some `orig...` fields. Amongst them are

- [`biblatex-archaeology`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-archaeology)
- [`biblatex-chicago`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago)
- [`biblatex-dw`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-dw)
- [`biblatex-oxref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-oxref)
- [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy)
- [`biblatex-sbl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-sbl)
- [`windycity`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/windycity)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I will use `biblatex-oxref`. I did not know about the `related` field.